# JavaFX Text - How to define the size in pixels, align it correctly and select a suitable font with the same letter width?

Tags: java, javafx, text, fonts, text-alignment

```
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBoundsType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextSize extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.YELLOWGREEN);
        var text = new Text(0, 50, "EXAMPLING");
        text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 100));
        text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL); // Removes text padding, but not the one on the left.
        text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER); // Doesn't align text horizontally.
        text.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER); // Aligns text vertically.
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, text)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

I need to edit the text.

1. I primarily want to set the correct `Text` size. Specifically, the distance between the `Text` and each edge of the `Rectangle` should be at least 5 pixels. I could achieve this by defining the size of the `Text` in pixels. In this case, the text height should be a maximum of 90px and the text length should be a maximum of 590px. However, the font size is not defined in pixels. Even if I enter it using fxml, it has no effect. How do I define it, please?
2. I want to place the text in the center of the `Rectangle`. Therefore, I need the position of the `Text` to define its center. `var text = new Text(300, 50, "EXAMPLING");` But, as I said in the comments in the code, I couldn't align the text horizontally and remove the padding on the left (As can be seen from the picture). You will probably say that I should use [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html). But, this is just an example, so I want to know if it can be achieved without it, please?
3. This Font has all the letters the same width, but I don't like it very much. Do you know of a better Font (Arial style), which also has the same width letters?

Please help.

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I solved the size(1.) and font(3.) of the text using this code.

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 100, Color.YELLOWGREEN);
var text = new Text(0, rectangle.getHeight() * 0.5, "EXAMPLING");
text.setFont(Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("GT Pressura Mono Regular Regular.ttf"), rectangle.getHeight() * 1.3));
text.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
var max_width = rectangle.getWidth() - 7;
for (var i = text.getFont().getSize() - 0.5; text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() >= max_width; i -= 0.5) {
    text.setFont(new Font(text.getFont().getName(), i));
}
text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
text.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);
stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(rectangle, text)));
stage.show();
```

[image]

However, I still don't know how to solve the positioning(2.).

Comment: 1. You can set the font size in pixels using CSS. You can ensure there are 5 pixels to the left by setting x to 5 (instead of 0), though a better way is to use a pane and set padding. The relationship between height and width depends on the text and font used, so you can't specify both of those. 2.  As you stated, the correct approach is to place the text in a layout pane (where you can set the padding and background color, as well as the alignment). The only way to do this without a layout pane (eg `HBox`) basically means reproducing all the functionality already defined there. Why do that?

Comment: 3. There are many monospaced fonts (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) but you'd need to ensure the one you want is installed on the client machine.

Comment: @James_D I solved the size and font of the text, but the code is too complicated, so I added it to the question. I don't know if it's optimal, but it works. I downloaded the [font](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/226f58ab113a6d821def90a7d6dc2427). But I don't know how to solve the positioning problem. To make you understand, this is just an example for simplicity, but the actual code looks different and using a layout would be quite difficult. That's why I wanted to know if this can be achieved without a layout. Even by some calculation. The problem is the mysterious gap on the left.